# getting vim to autocomplete python methods

Tags: autocompletion, filetype-python, plugin-jedi-vim, plugin-deoplete

I am coming from statically types languages, but I will have to be using python for the next few years and I want to get my setup as smooth as possible.

Right now I am using vim-jedi, and deoplete-jedi for python autocompletion. It's a dynamic language, so static analysis is not as good as it is for static languages and I find myself having to google library docs often which is really REALLY annoying. For example...

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# jedi will complete the next lines subplot function
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# on the instantiated class I get no autocompletion whatsoever, if I want to see the methods, I have to google docs
ax.set_title('...')
```

I want to be able to see the instantiated class methods without having to go outside of vim. The best would be...

1. If I could get the method autocompletion to work
2. If I could pull up the docs for that class (vim-jedi, will pull up docs on the subplot method, but then i'll have to chase down what it returns, etc which is probably harder than just googling so I need a faster way to get to it)

Does anyone know if there is a way to accomplish what I want, or do I just have to leave and google everything when I need to see methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had moderate success with [pydoc.vim](https://github.com/fs111/pydoc.vim) for documentation; it can be helpful to use a virtualenv/run `setup.py develop`, but you may still have to point it at the right python.

I’ve also had moderate success with tags (I use universal ctags and [these hooks](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/tree/master/links/git_template/hooks) to keep them up to date). With tags, I can quickly jump to the source and read a docstring. Occasionally it sends me to my tests instead of the source, so I need to use `g<C-]>`.

I haven’t used it, but [kite](https://kite.com/) may work for you. They have a vim plugin as well.

Comment: +1 for ctags. Personally, I found [vim-gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) works great for me to keep the tags file updated. YMMV.

Comment: vim-jedi will find documentation like pydoc (unless pydoc does something super magical that I don't know) but it comes back to the problem that after that class is instantiated, no one know what it is. If it was known then autocompletion would work and I would be able to open the docs, but we just don't know what it is. Kite looks way to heavy handed for me. I am not familiar with ctags as I have never used them before. Can they infer instantiated classes as I mentioned?

Comment: @deltaskelta tags are about navigating the codebase, so with them you should be able to quickly jump to definitions and find docstrings on methods. It isnt perfect (usually fairly regex-based), but it works. IOW, it doesnt care about types of variables (unless they are type)—but it can find a method that you call given it’s name, which is really the point. I do prefer the git hooks only because it’s completely invisible to me, but i can run it manually if i need to (i have an alias set up for it). As filbranden says, YMMV. I agree that Kite seems heavy

Comment: if it's regexing for methods I call, meaning methods that I already type, then it wont work for me. I want to deal with the situation where I don't know the method name and something helps me find it (..."is that matplotlib method called `set_title` or `title` kind of questions)

Comment: @deltaskelta fair enough—though I believe thats exactly the problem kite solves